# Haskell tuple monad is too strict?

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation

I was writing my code with `Control.Monad.Writer.Lazy` using `(,) [String]` as my writer monad. But I found that `(>>=)` and `(>>)` are too strict with the monoid operator? They cause infinte loop with this code for example:

```hs
type Wrtr a = ([String], a)
writer (x, w) = (w, x)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let one = writer ((), ["goodbye"])
    let w = foldr1 (>>) $ repeat one
    let (log, _) = w
    mapM_ putStrLn . take 5 $ log
```

This code will loop endlessly and never print anything and it's bad for me. So for now I'm using this naive implementation of the same monad, which seems to be fine and lazy:

```hs
data Writer w a = Writer w a
instance Functor (Writer w) where
    fmap f (Writer w x) = Writer w (f x)
instance Monoid w => Applicative (Writer w) where
    pure x = Writer mempty x
    (Writer w1 f) <*> (Writer w2 x) = Writer (w1 <> w2) (f x)
instance Monoid w => Monad (Writer w) where
    return = pure
    (Writer w1 x) >>= f =
        let (Writer w2 y) = f x
        in Writer (w1 <> w2) y
writer (x, w) = Writer w x
```

(You have to define functor and applicative instances because of monoid constraint)

If you then run the code with the same exact `main` function as above, it will print "goodbye" five times and exit.

So the question is: why are tuples so strict? Or if it's not strictness, what is it and why is it there?

BTW I'm using ghc 8.6.4 and everything else whihch comes with stack lts-13.19

Comment: I don't understand the part "I was writing my code with Control.Monad.Writer.Lazy using (,) [String] as my writer monad." If you are using the `(,) [String]` monad, you are not using `Control.Monad.Writer.Lazy`. I guess the `base` monad `(,) [String]` is isomorphic to `Control.Monad.Writer.Strict.Writer [String]` instead, which should loop on your code (once adapted).

Comment: I god damn I read it all wrong. I thought this module only exported instances and methods, didn't notice the `Writer` itself. Time to test it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hackage says](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-436)

```
instance Monoid a => Monad ((,) a) where
    (u, a) >>= k = case k a of (v, b) -> (u <> v, b)
```

and this means they are strict  because of the `case` (unlike your `let (Writer w2 y) = f x`):

```
foldr1 (>>) $ repeat one
= one >> foldr1 (>>) (repeat one)
= (["goodbye"], ()) >>= \_ -> foldr1 (>>) (repeat one)
= case ((\_ -> foldr1 (>>) (repeat one)) ()) of (v, b) -> (["goodbye"] <> v, b)
= case (foldr1 (>>) (repeat one)) of (v, b) -> (["goodbye"] <> v, b)
```

and this actually forces the nested `(foldr1 (>>) ...)` before you can ever access the `["goodbye"] <> v` part.

This is because `case` pattern matching is forcing but `let` patterns are lazy. Your code in effect writes the above as

```
= let (v, b) = foldr1 (>>) (repeat one) in (["goodbye"] <> v, b)
```

and all is fine and lazy.

Comment: Oh thanks, I looked into the source code but didn't know about this behvaiour of `case .. of`

Answer (score 5):

That's because your `Writer` violates the monad laws. Look at this law:

```
-- forall (f :: a -> Writer m b) (x :: a).
return x >>= f = f x
-- basically f (id x) = f x, which we should agree is pretty important!
```

But, alas, it doesn't hold! `let f = undefined`! (or `f = const undefined`; they are indistinguishable if you don't use `seq`)

```
  return x >>= undefined
= Writer mempty x >>= undefined
= let (Writer m y) = undefined
  in  Writer (mempty <> m) y
= Writer (mempty <> undefined) undefined
```

Yet, by law,

```
  return x >>= undefined
= undefined x
= undefined
```

These are not equivalent, therefore your lazy `Monad` instance is unlawful (and yes, I believe so is the one in `mtl`). However, [Fast and Loose Reasoning is Morally Correct](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/fast+loose.pdf), so we generally just accept it. The idea is that a lazy `Writer` monad generally follows the laws its supposed to, as long as you keep infinite or bottoming values out of it, but it breaks down at those edge cases. In contrast, the strict implementation is *completely* lawful, and that is why it is in `base`. However, as you've discovered, when lazy `Writer`s break the law, they do it in a useful manner, so we place the lazy implementation in `mtl`.

Here is a [demo of this behavior](https://repl.it/@howtonotwin/Writers). Notice that the lazy version produces a `Writer "` in the output before blowing up, while both the strict version and the specification given by the law don't do so.

Comment: `base` has some similarly unlawful instances, including `Bifunctor (,)` and `Arrow (->)`. I find it a bit distressing.

Comment: @dfeuer: What’s unlawful about them? For the `Arrow` instance `arr f = f; (f *** g) ~(x, y) = (f x, g y)`, does the lazy match make it more defined than it’s supposed to be for `first (first f) >>> arr assoc = arr assoc >>> first f`? The definition of `assoc ((a, b), c) = (a, (b, c))` seems suspect in the first place.

Comment: @JonPurdy, okay, to be fair, I'm not sure about `Arrow`, but I'd certainly *expect* `first id = id`, which is not strictly satisfied.

Comment: Another not-quite-monad in `base`: lazy `ST`.

Comment: That's a really nice answer, thanks! I always forget about the bottom.